# Install WIndows XP on a PC without PS2 adapter

Tags: windows-xp, installation, usb

I have a new PC that comes with USB but without PS2 adapter. I need to install Windows XP 64 bit incl. SP1. The keyboard works in the BIOS and during the installation of Windows XP. But when the XP login screen appears, I obviously don't know anything about the USB keyboard.

Can I use the recovery console to configure Windows XP using the USB keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say "obviously"? That's not obvious at all. If the USB keywoard works during Windows setup, it should work when Windows is installed, too; Windows uses exactly the same drivers in the setup phase and when it's actually running.

Have you tried waiting a few minutes after the login screen comes up? Also, have you tried plugging it out and then in again when you are at that screen?

Comment: Plugging out and in did not help. Reinstalling Windows did. ;-(

Answer (score 0):

The USB keyboard should function the same, especially if it was recognized by the system BIOS. Is it not functioning?

Answer (score 0):

when its at the screen, try unplugging it and replugging it in, then wait a few minutes. It might need to redetect and the device and pull its drivers.

Comment: This process may take anywhere between 10 seconds and 30 seconds for a first-time detection.